# Pushing changes to branch other than main

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push, remote-repository

I cloned a repo from github I made, I did some changes. My repo on github has 2 branches, `main` and `dev`. I want to push my changes to dev first and then main.

I ran:

```sh
git branch
```

while in the cloned (local) repo, giving me the output:

```sh
*main
```

I don't see my dev branch I made on github.

How can I push my changes to the dev branch?

Comment: to get info on how to create branch from terminal and how to work on github please read the [docs](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently,

```sh
git branch dev
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
git push origin dev:dev
```

worked.

Answer (score 3):

As [knittl said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72136858/1256452), `git branch` shows *your* branch names.  Some other Git repository, such as the repository over on GitHub, will have *its own* branch names.

What's important in Git is not actually the *branch names*.  These are for *you*, not for Git.  More precisely, they exist so that Git can help you find the *commits* you want.  This is because Git is really all about *commits*, not about branches—though we organize our commits *into* branches—and not about files, although each commit holds a snapshot of files.

This means that when you use Git, you must think first and foremost about *commits*.  You need to know, at a sort of gut level, exactly what a commit is and does for you.  Otherwise all the crazy things that Git does will be frustrating and impossible, and [you will live in this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1597/).

#### Git is all about commits, so what is a commit?  What does it do for you?

Each Git commit:

- Is numbered.  Each commit has a *unique* number, expressed as a *hash ID* (or *object ID*) in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  This is the commit's [true name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name), without which Git cannot *find* the commit.  (For fun, see also the [TV trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName).)  Hash IDs are large and ugly and impossible for humans to remember (or in most cases, pronounce ), so Git lets us use shortened versions sometimes.
- Is completely, totally, read-only: frozen for all time.  That's because the number, once assigned, means *that* commit, and it means that in *every repository*.  When your Git repository sends this commit off to some other Git repository, that other Git will use *the same number*.  It will never use that number for *any other commit*, not even *before* you make that commit.  (This is where the magic is, in Git, and if you know hashing theory, cryptography, and so on, you'll know that this literally *can't* work.  Someday, Git will fail.  The sheer size of the hash ID pushes that time as far into the future as we need, or at least, we hope it does.)
- Contains two things: a snapshot of *all* of the files that Git knew about at the time you (or whoever) *made* the commit, and some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself, such as the name of the person who made it.

There is a bunch of information in the metadata for each commit, but the key item for Git itself is that each commit contains a *list*—usually just one entry long—of the raw hash IDs of the *previous* commit or commits.  Git calls these the *parents* of the commit.

The snapshot in each commit freezes every file for all time, so that anyone who has the repository can get back any version of every file.  These files are stored in a special format that only Git can read, and literally nothing can write, and they're all *de-duplicated* within and across commits, so the fact that most commits mostly re-use the files from earlier commits means that most commits take very little *real* space.  If you make a new commit that completely re-uses old files—this is possible in several ways—then the new commit literally takes no space at all for the files, and just a little space to hold its own metadata.

The snapshot means that a commit gives you the power to view *every file* exactly as it stood at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.  But you can't use the committed file as a *file*, because it's in a special Git-only format, and you can't *write* to it as your computer would like to.  So this means that to *use* a snapshot, you have to have Git *extract* it.  We won't get into any of the details here, but this is what `git checkout` or `git switch` is doing when you switch to a particular commit: Git *extracts* the committed files, as if from an archive (because they *are* in an archive).  You then work with or on the extracted files, *not* the files stored in Git.  **That means when you're working with files, those are files that are not in Git.**  You'll eventually have to make a new commit, to store a new snapshot into Git.

Meanwhile, the metadata gives you several things:

- It lets you know *who made the commit*.  The `git log` command will print the user's name and email address, and a date-and-time stamp.  (With `--pretty=fuller` you'll see that there are actually two of these per commit; this is partly leftover from Git's early "everyone sends patches via email" usage.)
- It tells you what they wanted to tell you about *why* they made the commit: this is their *log message*.  The point of a log message is not to say *what* they did—Git can show that by comparing the snapshot in *this* commit to the snapshot in this commit's parent—but rather *why* they replaced `i++` with `i += 2` for instance.  Did it fix Bug#123?  Was it a feature enhancement?  That sort of thing can go in the log message.
- Using that parent metadata, Git can *string the commits together, backwards*.  This is the history: this is what happened in this project, over time.  By reading out the *latest* commit, we find the current source snapshot, and by using its metadata, we find its earlier parent commit.  Using the stored hash ID, Git can now show you the *parent* commit.  That commit contains the hash ID of a still-earlier grandparent commit, so Git can now show you the grandparent; that commit contains a still-earlier commit hash ID, and so on.

**This means that the commits in the repository *are* the history in the repository.**  To access *all* the history, Git needs the *latest* commit.

#### Branch names help you (and Git) *find* the latest commit

Let's draw some commits.  We'll pretend we have a tiny repository with just three commits in it.  They'll have three random-looking, big-and-ugly hash IDs that nobody can remember or pronounce, so we'll call them commits `A`, `B`, and `C` instead.  Commit `C` will be the latest, so it will have, in its metadata, the actual hash ID of earlier commit `B`.  We say that commit `C` *points to* commit `B`, and we draw that like this:

```
    B <-C
```

But `B` is a commit, so it has a list of parent hash IDs—just one commit long again—which means that `B` points to its parent `A`:

```
A <-B <-C
```

`A` is also a commit, but, being the *very first commit ever*, it has a list of *no* parents (an empty list of parents) and doesn't point backwards.  That's how `git log` knows to stop going backwards: there's just nothing left.

But: how does Git find the correct hash ID to *extract* commit `C` so that you can work on / with it in the first place?  Remember, the hash IDs look random.  They are unpredictable (because, among other things, they depend exquisitely on the exact second at which you make the commit).  There's only one way to know the hash ID, and that's to have it saved: written down somewhere.  We could write them down ourselves, and then have to type them in over and over again, but that's no fun at all.  So Git stores them for us.  **This is what a branch names is.**  A branch name simply stores *one* hash ID, namely the ID of the *latest commit*.

If we have one branch named `main`, then, and `C` is the latest commit for `main`, then the name `main` holds the hash ID of commit `C`.  As before, we say that this *points to* commit `C`, and draw it with an arrow:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main
```

At this point I like to get lazy and stop drawing the arrows from commit backwards to previous commit *as* arrows, because of what's about to happen to the drawings and because I don't have a good "arrow font" available.  This is OK because once we make a commit, the backwards-pointing arrow from that commit to its parent is frozen for all time, like all parts of any commit.  It *has* to point backwards, because we don't know what any *future* hash ID might be, so we just know they point backwards:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

The arrows coming from *branch names*, however, *change over time*.  Let's make a new commit on `main`, by using `git switch main` or `git checkout main` to select commit `C` as the commit we'll work on / with, and then doing some work and running `git add` and `git commit` to make a new commit `D`, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D
```

New commit `D` points backwards to previous commit `C`.  But now `D`—whatever its real hash ID is—is the latest commit, so the name `main` needs to point to `D`.  So the last step of `git commit` is that Git *writes `D`'s hash ID into the name `main`:*

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- main
```

(and now we could draw the whole thing on one line again).

What happens if, before we make `D`, we create a *new branch name*, say `dev`?  Let's draw one in and watch what happens:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev, main
```

We make our new commit `D`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

**Which name gets updated?**  The answer for Git is simple: *Git updates whichever branch name we have checked out.*  So we need to know, are we using the name `main` now, or are we using the name `dev` now?

To remember which name we're using, we'll add the special name `HEAD` to exactly one branch name, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
```

This means we're using commit `C`, but doing so because of / through the name `main`.  If we `git switch dev` or `git checkout dev`, we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

We're still using commit `C` but now we're using it through the *name* `dev`.  If we make our commit `D` *now* we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

There are now *two* latest commits: `C` is the latest `main` commit, and `D` is the latest `dev` commit.  Note that commits up through `C` are *on both branches*, and the fact that `D` is the latest `dev` commit doesn't interfere with the fact that `C` is the latest `main` commit.

Suppose we switch back to `main` (and draw `dev` "above" instead of "below" if we like):

```
        D   <-- dev
       /
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We've gone back to *using commit `C`*, so we see the files from commit `C`, rather than those from commit `D`.  If we now create, and switch to, a new branch named `br2`, we get this:

```
        D   <-- dev
       /
A--B--C   <-- br2 (HEAD), main
```

We're still using commit `C` but now we're doing so *through the name `br2`*.  If we make a new commit *now* we get:

```
        D   <-- dev
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        E   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

**This is what Git branches are all about.  The *name* finds the latest commit, and from there we / Git work backwards.**  The set of commits that we *find* as we work backwards is the set of commits that is "on" the branch, and that is the history of that branch.

The names find the *latest* commits, by definition.  This allows us to "turn back time" by forcing one of the branch names to back up a commit or two or three, too.  We do this when we use `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to "erase" a commit: it doesn't actually go away, we just pretend we never made it by making sure that we can't *find* it with the branch name.  For instance, if we're on `br2` and make a *bad* commit `F`:

```
        D   <-- dev
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        E--F   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

we can use `git reset --hard HEAD~1` (or `git reset --hard hash-of-E`) to get this:

```
        D   <-- dev
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        E   <-- br2 (HEAD)
         \
          F   ??? [abandoned]
```

Then we can make a corrected commit `G`:

```
        D   <-- dev
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        E--G   <-- br2 (HEAD)
         \
          F
```

Since there's no way to *find* `F`, we'll never see it again, and it seems as though it's gone.  (Git will *probably*, eventually—after 30 or more days—decide that we really don't want it, and drop it entirely, but commits are hard to get rid of.  If you *did* save the hash ID somewhere, on paper for instance or in a file, and feed it *to* `git show` for instance, you may find that commit `F` is still there.  When and even whether Git *really* does away with it is deliberately kept a bit of a mystery.)

#### Multiple repositories

A *Git repository* consists mainly of two databases:

- There's one (usually much larger) that holds commit objects and other supporting objects.  Git calls this its *object database* or *object store* and Git needs the hash ID to find objects inside this database.
- Separately, there's a second (usually much smaller) database of names—branch names, tag names, and many other names—that Git uses to *find* the commits and other objects.  Each name holds exactly one hash ID.

We can connect one Git database to another.  When we do so, the two Git software packages use the hash IDs to exchange *objects*.  Both repositories will use the *same hash IDs* for the same objects, so they can tell which objects the other one has just by comparing hash IDs.  Then one Git—whichever one is *sending* stuff—sends over just the objects the other one *needs*, using the objects it already has to avoid sending stuff it doesn't need.

In this way, the two repositories wind up *sharing commits*.  They literally have the same objects with the same hash IDs, so they share the commits with each other.  Both have a full copy of everything.

*Branch names* in this names database, however, are specific to this particular repository.  We may have our Git *show* them to some other Git, and that other Git can grab those names and hash IDs and do something with them, but they're *our* branch names.  *Tag* names in this database, we try to share: if some other Git repository also has tag names, we try to use their names as-is, and share our tag names with them as-is, so that `v1.2` means the same hash ID in both repositories.  But *branch* names aren't shared this way!  Each repository has *its own*.

Instead of sharing branch names, then, when you run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`, you're telling your Git: *Call up their Git software, have it connect to their repository, and find me all their latest commits via their branch branch names.  Then bring over all the commits.  Take all their **branch** names and change those into my **remote-tracking** names.*  Their `main` becomes your `origin/main`; their `dev` becomes your `origin/dev`; and so on.  That way, whether or not they have added commits to *their* branches, *your* branches aren't disturbed.  You get any new commits they have, and your *remote-tracking* names remember their latest commit hash IDs.

But this is not true for `git push`.

#### "Non-fast-forward" errors from `git push`

When you run `git push origin` or `git push origin dev`, you have your Git call up their Git software and repository just the same way you did for `git fetch`, but this time you choose to have *your* Git send *your* new commits *to them*.  Instead of having your Git read their branch names and find *their* new-to-*you* commits, you have your Git send over hash IDs and find *your* new-to-*them* commits.  Your Git then hands over these new commit objects to them ... and then asks or commands them to set one of their **branch** names.  They don't have remote-tracking names for you!  You just ask them to set their *branch* names directly.

Suppose you have:

```
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
```

in *your* repository, but *they* acquired some commit `E` in *their* repository like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main [their main, in their repository]
       \
        E   <-- dev [their dev, in their repository]
```

Your Git sends over your new-to-them commit `D` and asks them to set their `dev` to remember commit `D`.

**If they did that**—which they won't—how will they find their commit `E`?  Remember, *their* Git is going to use *their branch names* to find the latest commit.  If their `dev` moves to locate commit `D`, and `D` doesn't lead to `E`—and it doesn't—they'll "lose" *their* commit `E`.

If that kind of thing is going on, they will say: *No, I won't set my `dev` to remember `D` as the latest commit, because that would lose some other latest commit(s).*  This shows up at your `git push` as:

```
! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to ...
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When this happens, you need to:

1. run `git fetch` to get any new commits *they* have that *you* lack;
2. *inspect your and their commits* and the relationships (parent, child, sibling, etc.), that these commits may have to each other: use `git log` with various options; see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452;)
3. *rework your commits* if and as necessary, e.g., using `git rebase`;
4. repeat your `git push` now that you've corrected things, or use `git push --force-with-lease` if you're sure that you are *supposed to* tell their Git repository *yes, lose those commits!*

This *is* a lot of stuff to know.  But if you're going to work with Git and distributed repositories, you need to know it.  It should all be at least *vaguely* familiar, and the concept of *commits* and what they do for you should be *very* familiar.

Comment: bruh! you wrote whole article, 
edit: after giving it a read, it explains the branching concept quite easily

Answer (score 1):

`git branch` only shows local branches, to show remote branches use `git branch -r` (to show local *and* remote branches, use `git branch -a`).

You can push any local to branch to any remote branch, by specifying the source (local) and target (remote) branch:

```
git push origin main:dev
```

will push the commits on your local main branch to the remote dev branch in the repository "origin".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
git fetch
git checkout dev
git add .
git commit -m "your commit message here"
git push
```

`git fetch` will get an update of all existing branch from your remote repo into your local. Then, you can do `git checkout dev` to switch to `dev` branch. Then  finally `commit` and `push` to `dev`

Then to push to `main`, you can make a `pull request`, approve it, and merge to `main`.